# How can I have a TFrame Styled at Design Time in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am using Delphi XE5 up 2.

Based with seems to be the correct rules, I am writing an application that has only one form and lots of frames (TFrame) in firemonkey.

I have a StyleBook on my mainform, and it works well. When the Frame is inserted during runtime it works fine.

However I need to draw my frame using the style that I need. It needs to be at design time, since there are adjustments to be made, and I need to review many frames eventually.

Suggestions that did not work:

- Draw the contents on a form, when finished cut and paste on a frame: I expect better that that!
- Change the global style by resource: I have added as a resource with the platform name the style I wanted but I did not see any effect. (Project->resouces and images)
- I have tried to use a form and then insert it like a frame on my mainform, but I could not make it work.

So, is there a way to have my frame styled during design time?

or there is an alternative? (I need to draw in something that can be styled and then inserted at runtime when needed)

Comment: @SirRufo yes sir! done ! thank you! I wondered about that in the past, now I know for sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste StyleBook on main form and rename default style for component
Example: 
stylename "buttonstyle"
Rename it to "buttonstylemy"
when you manualy write "buttonstylemy" to Button StyleLookup  in frame you will see result

Complicated but better than nothing

Sorry for English